# PHP changing the index of multidimentional array to value of variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array

Pretty new to PHP. I have a csv feed that i am trying to display every line of in the right place. The feed is loaded into a multidimentional array and I can echo out specific places like this.

```
echo $readcsv[0][2]
```

But I am trying to use the value of the variable $row in stead of the first number while doing a while loop.

Something like:

```
echo $readcsv[$row][2]
```

I have tried next(), str_replace() and strtr() but none of them seems to work while the loop is running.

```
$row = 1;
$readcsv = array(); 

if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);

        echo $readcsv[$row][2];

        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        }
        $mycsvfile[] = $data; 
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

CSV file:

```
title;image_link;link;empty;price;
1;back.gif;http://link.com;;19.95;
2;back.gif;http://link.com;;19.95;
3;back.gif;http://link.com;;19.95;
4;back.gif;http://link.com;;19.95;
5;back.gif;http://link.com;;19.95;
```

Comment: can you share your csv file?

Comment: Please explain what do you want to achieve, as your're reading the $readcsv array, and the 3rd key of the $readcsv[ $row ], which are empty. Turn on the error reporting, as the code will throw some errors

Comment: Is it as simple as arrays start with an index of 0

Comment: Or that you are trying to echo a value from `$readcsv` that does not actually exist until you create that index

Comment: Or in fact that `$readcsv` never gets anything loaded into it as after you create that array you never put anything into it

Comment: And which SO gave this question an upvote. Can I remind that person Upvote = _This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear_ DOWNVOTE = _This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful_

Comment: As far as i can see the $readcsv does have the data from csv file. Works when i echo inside of loop and outside. I am just trying to show a new line from the csv every time the loop runs its course.

Comment: Correct, you NEVER actually load anything into that array. _Not in the code you show us anyway_

Comment: Its really not clear WHAT you are trying to do in this code

Comment: I am trying to use the code to read a cvs file and be able to edit the right places before inserting into a mysql database

Comment: Ill try to be clearer:
I want it to loop and +1 to the first index of the array $readcsv every loop.

Loop 1:
echo $readcsv[0][2];

Loop 2:
echo $readcsv[1][2];

Loop 3:
echo $readcsv[2][2];

Hope this clarifise

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure from your code and question exactly what you are trying to do, but maybe its something like this

```
if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {

        // you load the line into $data and its a one dimentional array
        // occurance 2 is the `link` (http://link.com) if that what you want to echo
        echo $data[2];

        // as you have a loop, maybe you were trying to
        // echo each fields from the csv so you can do that like this
        foreach ($data as $idx => $value) {

            echo "Column $idx = $value";
        }
        $mycsvfile[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```